# Command to list all users with their UID?

Tags: command-line, users

How can I list all users along with their UIDs? I want to do this from the terminal.

Comment: cat /etc/passwd

Answer (score 35, accepted):

List all users with a `/home` folder:

```
awk -F: '/\/home/ {printf "%s:%s\n",$1,$3}' /etc/passwd
```

or all users with a `UID >= 1000`:

```
awk -F: '($3 >= 1000) {printf "%s:%s\n",$1,$3}' /etc/passwd
```

a combination

```
awk -F: '/\/home/ && ($3 >= 1000) {printf "%s:%s\n",$1,$3}' /etc/passwd
```

or for all entries

```
awk -F: '{printf "%s:%s\n",$1,$3}' /etc/passwd
```

More information [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/)

Answer (score 17):

You can find it easily by just using `cut` :

```
cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd
```

- `-d:` sets the delimiter as `:` for `cut`
- `-f1,3` extracts the field 1 and 3 only delimited by `:` from the `/etc/passwd` file

Check `man cut` to get more idea.

**Example :**

```
$ cut -d: -f1,3 /etc/passwd
root:0
daemon:1
bin:2
sys:3
sync:4
games:5
......
```

If you have `ldap` configured, to include the `ldap` users in the output :

```
getent passwd | cut -d: -f1,3
```

Comment: You should use `getent passwd` instead of /etc/passwd since the latter won't include ldap users

Comment: @Daenyth [My initial answer](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/645246/1) was that actually..then for the sake of simplification (and considering no `ldap`) i have moved to teh current one..anyway edited  :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to list all users including UID and GID information.

```bsh
for user in $(cat /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d":"); do id $user; done
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to list the UID and Username, the below command works better best on Solaris. They have two awk

awk -F: '($3 >=1000) {printf "%s:%s",$1,$3}' /etc/passwd

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way is to have webmin on your server and simply go to System > Users and Groups and there you have a nicely formatted list with all usernames & groups with their uid's, home directory etc.