# How to check if a new username is a system user?

Tags: command-line

I want to create a script that change a username.
I want to check if the user is not a system user.
My idea is to check /etc/passwd and pick only users with an ID between 1000 and 60000 and users that have a /home directory like

```
user:x:1005:1021::/home/user:/bin/sh
```

My grep command for now is like

```
egrep -E '1[0-9]{3}.*/home' /etc/passwd
```

As you can see, it doesn't match my [1000-60000] pattern nor the name

Comment: Minor point: `grep -E` is the same thing as `egrep`. There's no point in using both (`egrep -E`), just use `grep -E`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `awk` to find **local** users with id >= 1000:

```
awk -F: '$3>=1000 && $3!=65534 {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

To also check for a home folder below `/home`:

```
awk -F: '$3>=1000 && $3 != 65534 && $6 ~ /^\/home/ {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Replace `/etc/passwd` with `<(getent passwd)` to list all users including network accounts ...

See also [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410244/a-command-to-list-all-users-and-how-to-add-delete-modify-users), as well as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645236/command-to-list-all-users-with-their-uid).

Comment: Thanks! but how can I merge all my patterns e.g name + ID + /home?

Comment: Mind that this does not list LDAP users so is only useable for local users :)

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind. I didn't know